# Cannot create the second column of a 2 dimensions array with file content

Tags: arrays, bash

```
cat file.txt 
#useless comment 

anyString1 a   #another useless comment 
anyString2 b

anyString3 a
anyString4 a

anyString5 a
```

I want to put file.txt content into a 2 dimensions array (any number of rows, 2 columns), without comments or empty lines:

```
declare -A TAB 
i=0

while read -r LINE; 
 do
  for ((j=1; j<3; j++)) 
   do
    LINE=$(echo "${LINE}" | sed 's/#.*//g' | awk -v var="${j}", '{ print $var }') 
    #echo "${LINE}" | sed 's/#.*//g;/^$/d' | awk -v var="${j}" '{ print $var }'
    [[ -n "${LINE}" ]] && TAB[$i,$j]="${LINE}" || { i=$((i-1));break; }
   done
  i=$((i+1))

done<file.txt
```

that snippet does not take the input when j=2 (but it does when j=1); I verify that removing the comment at line 8.

I also tried:

```
LINE=$(echo "${LINE}" | sed 's/#.*//g;/^$/d' | cut -d' ' -f${j})
```

thanx folks!

Comment: `into a 2 dimensions array` Then use a different programming lnaguage. Bash does not have 2 dimensional arrays. `for ((j=1; j<3; j++)) ` wha tis that `j` doing? `var=${j}",` why is here a comma? `TAB[$i,$j]="${LINE}"` I do not fully understand, what is the point of such array? You want to have two elements with the same value? `does not take the input when j=2` You understand that when you `LINE=$()` you are overwriting `LINE` value?

Answer (score 0):

Do one thing at a time. First preprocess the file. Remove comments. Remove empty lines. Then read. Just read to array elements.

```
declare -A tab
content=$(sed 's/#.*//g; /^[[:space:]]$/d' file.txt)
i=0
while IFS=' ' read -r tab["$i,1"] tab["$i,2"]; do
   ((++i))
done <<<"$content"
```

or, like, with an intermediary array. Still, do the splitting just straight with `IFS` if possible, not with separate `awk` processes.

```
while IFS=' ' read -r -a tmp; do
   for ((j=0; j<${#tmp[@]}; ++j)); do
      tab["$i,$j"]="${tmp[j]}"
   done
   ((++i))
done <<<"$content"
```

> does not take the input when j=2

With `LINE=$(echo "${LINE}"...)` you are overwriting the variable value. The second time the loop runs, `LINE` variable has only the first element. Use a different variable.

Prefer to use lowercase variables for local variables.

Comment: .@KamilCuk:Of course. I just need to introduce a new variable and keep LINE untouched so that TAB can take the second column. You should have left an answer to get the point.